# Create link to sort columns PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sorting

I need to create links that allow someone to sort the data based on the column header. I was able to get a working model which sorts the data by ID either ASC or DESC. How could I create this same function for more than just the ID column?

```
<?php
    $order = (isset($_GET['sort']) && strcasecmp($_GET['sort'], 'desc') == 0) ? 'DESC' : 'ASC'; 
    $query = 'SELECT DISTINCT `case`, firstname, lastname FROM `cases` ORDER BY id ' . $order;   
          $result = mysql_query($query); 
    ?>

    <td><a href=<?php echo "'?sort=" . ($order == 'DESC' ? 'ASC' : 'DESC') . "'";?>>Case ID</a></td>
    <td>Name</td>

    <?php  
    // list records  
         while ($nt = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {    
    ?>

    <td><?php echo $nt['case']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $nt['firstname']; ?> <?php echo $nt['lastname']; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the column name or an alias (id, ...) in the URL just like the sorting direction.

Comment: But make sure to add a whitelist so people cannot inject bad stuffinto your SQL query.

Comment: Exactly. Prepare a list of allowed names and use a default value for any other.

Answer (score 0):

I would define an array to define your allowed sorts, so you don't send table names via links and the user ( a malicious user doesn't know what sort=1, 2, 3, etc do), and when you print your links  I disabled the link to the curent sort (You could use css to make it different from the rest of them so the user knows where it is ).
here is the code sample:

```
<?php
$sorts = array
(
    1=>array('order'=>' ORDER BY id', 'name'='case id'),
    2=>array('order'=>' ORDER BY id DESC', 'name'='case id desc'),
    3=>array('order'=>' ORDER BY firstname', 'name'='case firstname'),
    4=>array('order'=>' ORDER BY firstname DESC', 'name'='case firstname desc')
    // and so on
);

if(!is_numeric($_GET['sort']))
{
    echo 'Invalid sort type !';exit; // use your custom error reporting function.
}
    foreach($sorts as $key => $value)
    {
        $order = ($key == $_GET['sort'])?$value['order']:'';
        echo '<td><a href = "example.com?sort='.$_GET['sort'].'" '.(($key == $_GET['sort'])? disabled="disabled":'').'>'.$value['name'].'</a></td>';
    }


$query = 'SELECT DISTINCT case, firstname, lastname FROM cases '.$order;
// ...
```